# ES File Explorer can read and write to external sd cart but my program cannot? (android kitkat)

Tags: android, android-external-storage

Android ES file explorer can read and write in my tablet that OS version is kitkat ,ES can create folder, files and copy and delete in my external SD cart.

my application can write and create folder and files to internal storage but got error "Permission denied" for write in external SD cart. my app works on other version of android for write to external storage,
now my question is how to write external storage in kitkat like ES File Explorer?
my external storage is removable SD card.
(my tablet is not root)
sorry for my english

Comment: show us your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: this is my full androidMainfest.xml:
http://framesoft.ir/download/downloadonefile/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: By external SD do you mean a removable a micro SD card?

Comment: yes its removable SD card

Comment: Then it won't work. You cannot have wirte access to removable media with the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission on API 19 and above. You have to ask the user to give write access to the specific directory at run time. Refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html.

Comment: i read documents for storage access framework, but why es file explorer not show dialog for access to read and write my sd cart? i can read folder and files and create and delete without any question for get permissions

Comment: my app with storage access framework work on lollipop but not kitkat

Comment: In MarshMellow they have introduced Runtime permissions. Can you share the code with which you are writing to SD card? You current code.

Comment: yes, you can read my code in this file, this is my two method for get folder from user and i can create or write file:
http://framesoft.ir/download/downloadonefile/code.txt

Comment: and this is my storage access for file stream:

http://framesoft.ir/download/downloadonefile/provider.txt

Comment: this code works on lollipop, however i cannot see true path for files and directory but can read and write files from security path,but not work on kitkat.

Comment: code write with C#

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied suggests that you didn't acquire the permission to read from external storage, try adding the following line to the AndroidManifest.xml if you didn't

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This will make your app able to read files from your system. Also to write, add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: i already added read and write permissions,you can read my mainfest xaml:
http://framesoft.ir/download/downloadonefile/AndroidManifest.xml
i say my app works on another android version but not work on kitkat.